# Make a child view wider than its parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a RelativeLayout with an ImageView inside it.
The RelativeLayout is a ListView row and it has padding set (the space is between the edge of the ListView and the edge of its child RelativeLayout view).

I am trying to get the ImageView inside the RelativeLayout to be wider than the row using negative margins.
Set the negative margins and disabled clipping (all the way up).
Nothing seems to work.

Code example (the RelativeLayout has parents and space between its edge to the screen's edge):

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am not understanding quite well your rquirement but from what i understood give this a try: as your `ImageView` is a child of `RelativeLayout with  android:layout_width="match_parent"` what you have done wont work. Tyr adding `margin` to `RelativeLayout` instead. Otherwise you can give static `layout_width` to `RelativeLayout` and `ImageView` where width of `ImageView` is greater than `width of RelativeLAyout`

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this (the code is from a project that I was working on):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_heading_top_line"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/default_header_logo"
            android:layout_width="167dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/default_header_logo"
            android:contentDescription="@string/default_heading_logo" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It seems that clipping = false doesn't really work well in a RelativeLayout, so use a LinearLayout with a child - ImageView.

Comment: I have to use the RelativeLayout, the overall layout is too complex for LinearLayout. And I can't use absolute values for width and height.

Comment: "clipping = false doesn't really work well in a RelativeLayout" this information saved a lot of my time.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I sue`androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`, and set `android:clipToPadding="false"`, then set the child with negative margin, then it works.

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp_16"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp_16">
        <View
            android:id="@+id/gap"
            android:layout_marginStart="-16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-16dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```